# Keyboard pushes my EditText out of the screen

Tags: android

I have four EditText's in my Scrollview together with some checkbox and button:

- firstname
- lastname
- email
- password

  ```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/register_textedit_firstname"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:hint="@string/text_firstname"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:lines="1"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:scrollHorizontally="true"
      android:singleLine="true" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/register_textedit_lastname"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:hint="@string/text_lastname"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:lines="1"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:scrollHorizontally="true"
      android:singleLine="true" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/register_textedit_email"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:hint="@string/text_email"
      android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
      android:lines="1"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:scrollHorizontally="true"
      android:singleLine="true" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/register_textedit_password"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:hint="@string/text_password"
      android:inputType="textPassword"
      android:lines="1"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:scrollHorizontally="true"
      android:singleLine="true" />

  <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/register_checkbox_password"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/checkbox_showpassword" />

  <LinearLayout
      style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/register_button_register"
          style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="@string/button_register" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/register_button_cancel"
          style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="@string/button_cancel" />
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
  ```

The manifest for this activity:

```
<activity
        android:name="de.hof.ime_dc.idia_move.activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>
```

When i focus firstname or lastname the EditText for firstname gets pushed out of the top screen. I cant see it but i can type in it. when i focus email or password the firstname EditText comes back into the screen. I cant understand this behavoiur because when the firstname EditText gets pushed out of screen i cant scroll up to it (They are all in a ScrollView).

Dont get me wrong, i want my views to be pushed up when keyboard appears but i dont want them to get pushed out of the screen without being able to scroll to them.

EDIT

Just an idea:

Maybe it is because of my Action Title Bar? On every screen i have a action title bar with a navigation drawer. its seems that the edittext gets pushed under the title bar. Could that be?

EDIT 2

I noticed that it just happens on android device with android version 5.0.
A bug?

Comment: Show your AndroidManifest.xml also for this activity.

Comment: updated. there is nothing special here. i dont add ajustPan because as i wrote i want the view to be pushed up.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this in your `Manifest` .It works for me

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

I checked this .Please add this

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

For more information you can see this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: No, this also does not work because as i wrote i want the view to be pushed up if the keyboard does not fit. if i set adjustPan than it happens that the keyboard hides fields.

Comment: It does not work for me. The view does not get pushed up anymore when i add it. and fill_parent is btw. deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was, that i added this to my layouts:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

That was the root of the evil.

Comment: Oh. That case .Move ahead .

Answer (score 1):

You can add "adjustResize" to your Manifest file to resolve such kind of bug -

```
<application ... >
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" ... >
        ...
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: unfortunately `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` does not change anything.